# shipment has been lost vs ~is missing

Tags: tenses, passive-voice

My question is

**A million dollars' worth of shipment is missing**

and

**A million dollars' worth of shipment has been lost.**

Which sentence is correct?

Comment: Both are. They mean different things. The first sentence implies that the shipment may yet be found, while the second leaves open no such possibility.

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, it all depends on what you are trying to say.

Comment: Neither of these is idiomatic, because of the word *shipment*.  You would need an article, "*the* shipment*. But the "is missing" and "has been lost" are both OK.  If you have a particular noun, e.g. *lenses*, or *cocaine*, then you don't need an article. *A millions dollars' worth of cocaine is missing*.

Comment: What @TRomano said. I don't much like using *shipment* as a "mass noun" the way we do with, say, *cargo* or *product*.

Comment: I don't much like using 'shipment' or 'product' as a "mass noun" the way we do with, say, 'cargo' or 'goods'. However, there are precedents with 'product'.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it would be more natural to say "A shipment worth a million dollars...".

As to "is missing" vs "has been lost", the former implies that the shipment can't be located but may simply be in transit or whatever and might show up on its own.

Since "lost" has two somewhat different meanings in this sort of context, "has been lost" implies either that the disappearance is permanent or that the "loss" was the result of carelessness (or both).

Comment: What if only a portion of the shipment has gone missing?

Comment: Succint and complete. +1

Comment: @TRomano - If only part of the shipment is missing then one would say something like "Part of a million dollar shipment ..." or "Part of a shipment worth a million dollars ..."

Comment: What if the part that is missing is being valued? Say the total shipment was worth $10million, and the part that has gone missing is worth $1 million. My point is that it's not clear from the original question whether a portion of a shipment or an entire shipment has gone missing.

Comment: @TRomano - Well, you could say "Items worth $1 million are missing from a $10 million shipment," but really the statement would need to be "customized" to the context, and there's no good way to provide a "formula" for the various possibilities.